# How to manage AFNetworking request number?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking

In my iOS App,I have hundreds of image download.

I use AFNetworking to get those images.I want to manage the request number of AFWorking.

This is my code:

The problem is:It will block my UI.

THX for help me!

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(5);

for (NSString *urlString in self.downloadImageList) {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSString *filename = url.lastPathComponent;
        NSURL *outputFileURL = APPLICATION_DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY;
        outputFileURL = [outputFileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/images/%@",self.boardId,filename]];

        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamWithURL:outputFileURL append:YES];
            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                [self.downloadImageList removeObject:urlString];
                NIDINFO(@"download success %@",filename);
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NIDERROR(@"download image error:%@\n%@",error,urlString);
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            }];
            [operation start];
        });

    });
}

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(semaphore);
dispatch_release(group);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is: It will block my UI.

Well yeah, that's sort of the point of `dispatch_semaphore_t`. If you remove those calls, your AFNetworking calls will execute asynchronously in the background without affecting your main / UI thread.

I don't know the full context of where this code is being used, but it looks like you may want to consider having the method that calls this take a block parameter, that can be called once all of the requests have finished. You may also want to take a look at AFHTTPClient's batch operations features, which allows you to track the progress of a group of operations, getting callbacks for each individually, and when all of then finish.